# IIS is consuming large portion of the memory

Tags: html, xml, iis

I am supporting an Banking App which is working on 3 web servers. Since last week we experience havy memory usage from the IIS on all of the 3 web servers. The usage is above 50% (about 4 GB goes only for IIS Worker). Could you please help with ideas what could be the reason for this ?
Users are not more than before. So this I guess is not related to number of users logged in and using the app. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of site(e.g. Asp.Net, .Net Core, etc.) you have hosted on the IIS? which Server OS and IIS version you are using? Does the memory usage increase gradually over time or does it spike for a short time? Please check whether there is any change in your app code, IIS configuration or recently any updates that got installed. What are the overall CPU usage and memory usage of the machine? Further if you are familiar with analyzing the dumps then you could collect them via [DebugDiag Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58210#:~:text=The%20Debug%20Diagnostic%20Tool)

Comment: Hello. The site is Asp.Net. The Server is Windows 2016 Server. The memory usage increase gradually over time. Ever after a full restart of the web server the memory usage again creases over time. There is no change in the app code. The overall CPU usage peaks to 90% and for few seconds reaches 100% after which it drops again to 80%. The memory usage is again above 60-70%.

Comment: It could be possible that there might be a memory leak. To verify it and confirm it, you need to collect and analyze the dumps. If you are not familiar with it then you could create a support ticket with Microsoft.